# Cant set a div in front of another one in ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net

I am creating a simple login system but looks like the divs interact with each other. Div2 gets in front of Div1:

[image: Image 1]

There are a few labels and the rest of the text buttons behind the red div.

My ASP.NET code:

```
<div id ="LoginPannel"> /* <-- this is div 1*/
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username" Font-Bold="True" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Having Problems?" OnClick="Button3_Click" />


</div>

<div id="topForm"> /* <-- this is div 2 */


</div>
```

And the code behind 2 divs is this.

CSS code:

```
#LoginPannel{
   border-style: none;
   background-color:   #263540;
   position:absolute; 
   top: 42%;
   left:25%;
   width:268px;
   height: 115px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#topForm {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are just missing `z-index: 1;` in your Login panel.

---

```css
#LoginPannel {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #263540;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 42%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 268px;
  height: 115px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#topForm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="LoginPannel">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Having Problems?" OnClick="Button3_Click" />


</div>

<div id="topForm">


</div>
```

Comment: yea, looks like I put the z-index to 100. 
when I set it to -1 it got in the back. 
but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the login panel inside the top form div so that it remains inside it and on top of it.

```
<div id="topform">

    <div id="LoginPanel"> ... </div>

</div>
```